# Check for null in foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, null

Is there a nicer way of doing the following:
I need a check for null to happen on file.Headers before proceeding with the loop

```
if (file.Headers != null)
{
  foreach (var h in file.Headers)
  {
   //set lots of properties & some other stuff
  }
}
```

In short it looks a bit ugly to write the foreach inside the if due to the level of indentation happening in my code.

Is something that would evaluate to

```
foreach(var h in (file.Headers != null))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

possible?

Comment: You can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937407/null-exception-handling-in-foreach-loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872323/method-call-if-not-null-in-c-sharp is another idea.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu I think that's completely different. The question checks if the collection is null first before doing the for-each. Your link checks if the item in the collection is null.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3088147/80161 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6455311/80161

Comment: C# 8 could simply have a null-conditional foreach of some sort, i.e. syntax like this:

    foreach? (var i in collection)
    {
    }

I think it's a common enough scenario to justify this, and given the recent null-conditional additions to the language it makes sense here to?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Just as a slight cosmetic addition to [Rune's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11734449/112407), you could create your own extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrEmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Then you can write:

```
foreach (var header in file.Headers.OrEmptyIfNull())
{
}
```

Change the name according to taste :)

Comment: to satisfy Roslyn ```this IEnumerable<T> source``` should be ```this IEnumerable<T>? source```

Comment: @Pawel: Well that depends on the setting for nullable reference types - which didn't even exist in 2012. If you decide to go through every C# answer on Stack Overflow for 14 years and comment on every one of them that doesn't comply with an optional feature that didn't exist at the time, it's going to take you a *very* long time, with little tangible benefit.

Comment: I agree @Jon. I meant to improve (valuable) answer not to complain.

Comment: @Pawel: My point is that there are *millions* of such answers. Anyone using nullable reference types should be aware that they haven't always existed, and be able to change their code accordingly. Note that if I *did* change it as suggested, the code would fail to compile in non-NRE-enabled contexts... and I hate the idea of every C# answer affected by this requiring two different versions of every code snippet.

Answer (score 111):

Assuming that the type of elements in file.Headers is T you could do this

```
foreach(var header in file.Headers ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()){
  //do stuff
}
```

this will create an empty enumerable of T if file.Headers is null. If the type of file is a type you own I would, however, consider changing the getter of `Headers` instead. `null` is the value of unknown so if possible instead of using null as "I know there are no elements" when null actually(/originally) should be interpreted as "I don't know if there are any elements" use an empty set to show that you know there are no elements in the set. That would also be DRY'er since you won't have to do the null check as often.

**EDIT** as a follow up on Jons suggestion, you could also create an extension method changing the above code to

```
foreach(var header in file.Headers.OrEmptyIfNull()){
  //do stuff
}
```

In the case where you can't change the getter, this would be my own preferred since it expresses the intention more clearly by giving the operation a name (OrEmptyIfNull)

The extension method mentioned above might make certain optimizations impossible for the optimizer to detect. Specifically, those that are related to IList using method overloading this can be eliminated

```
public static IList<T> OrEmptyIfNull<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
    return source ?? Array.Empty<T>();
}
```

Comment: @kjbartel's answer (at " stackoverflow.com/a/32134295/401246 " is the best solution, because it doesn't: a) involve performance degradation of (even when not `null`) degenerating the whole loop to LCD of `IEnumerable<T>` (as using ?? would), b) require adding an Extension Method to every Project, or c) require avoiding `null` `IEnumerables` (Pffft! Puh-LEAZE! SMH.) to begin with (cuz `null` means N/A, whereas empty list means, it's applicable but is currently, well, empty!, i.e. an Employee could have Commissions that's N/A for non-Sales or empty for Sales when they haven't earned any).

Comment: @Tom aside from _one_ null check there's no penalty for the cases where the enumerator is not null. Avoiding that check while also ensuring that the enumerable is not null is impossible. The code above requires the Headers to a an `IEnumerable`  which is more restrictive than the `foreach` requirements but less restrictive than the requirement of `List<T>` in the answer you link to. Which have the same performance penalty of testing whether the enumerable is null.

Comment: I was basing the "LCD" issue on the comment by Eric Lippert on Vlad Bezden's Answer in the same thread as kjbartel's Answer: "@CodeInChaos: Ah, I see your point now. When the compiler can detect that the "foreach" is iterating over a List<T> or an array then it can optimize the foreach to use value-type enumerators or actually generate a "for" loop. When forced to enumerate over either a list or the empty sequence it has to go back to the "lowest common denominator" codegen, which can in some cases be slower and produce more memory pressure....".  Agree it requires `List<T>`.

Comment: @tom The premise of the answer is that file.Headers are an IEnumerable<T> in which case the compiler can't do the optimization. It is however rather straight forward to extend the extension method solution to avoid this. See edit

Answer (score 31):

Frankly, I advise: just suck up the `null` test. A `null` test is **just** a `brfalse` or `brfalse.s`; everything else is going to involve much more work (tests, assignments, extra method calls, unnecessary `GetEnumerator()`, `MoveNext()`, `Dispose()` on the iterator, etc).

An `if` test is simple, obvious, and efficient.

Comment: You do make an interesting point Marc, however, I'm currently looking to lessen the indentation levels of the code. But I will keep your comment in mind when I need to take note of performance.

Comment: Just a quick note on this Marc.. years after I asked this question and need to implement some performance enhancements, your advice came in extremely handy. Thank you

Comment: It's been over 10 years since this question was asked. So my thought is Microsoft should give us some syntatic sugar to have the foreach do a null check. For example `foreach (var item in myList?) { ... }`. The compiler will then see the question mark and wrap an `if (myList == null)` statement around the foreach block. This would make it look cleaner, and the `?` is used for a similar purpose as a null-conditional operator `myList?.Select(...)` currently.

Answer (score 30):

Using [Null-conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) and ForEach() which works faster than standard foreach loop.
You have to cast the collection to List though.

```
   listOfItems?.ForEach(item => // ... );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation around your answer, stating explicitly why this solution works, rather than just a code one-liner

Comment: best solution for my case

Comment: by far the cleanest option

Answer (score 18):

the "if" before the iteration is fine, few of those "pretty" semantics can make your code less readable.

anyway, if the indentation disturbs your, you can change the if to check:

```
if(file.Headers == null)  
   return;
```

and you'll get to the foreach loop only when there is a true value at the headers property.

another option I can think about is using the null-coalescing operator inside your foreach loop and to completely avoid null checking.
sample:

```
List<int> collection = new List<int>();
collection = null;
foreach (var i in collection ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>())
{
    //your code here
}
```

(replace the collection with your true object/type)

Comment: Your first option will not work if there is any code outside the if statement.

Comment: I agree, the if statement is easy and cheap to implement compared to creating a new list, just for code beautification.

Answer (score 6):

The best answer in the year 2022 should be:

```
foreach (var h in file.Headers ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Replace `T` with your data type. if file.Headers is an array, use `Array.Empty<T>()` instead of `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`

Comment: Will not compile if your collection is an interface. ```Enumerable.Empty<T>()``` or ```Array.Empty<T>()``` is still more versatile in 2022.

Answer (score 3):

I am using a nice little extension method for these scenarios:

```
  public static class Extensions
  {
    public static IList<T> EnsureNotNull<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
      return list ?? new List<T>();
    }
  }
```

Given that Headers is of type list, you can do following:

```
foreach(var h in (file.Headers.EnsureNotNull()))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: you can use the `??` operator and shorten the return statement to `return list ?? new List<T>;`

Comment: @wolfgangziegler, If I understand correctly the test for `null` in your sample `file.Headers.EnsureNotNull() != null` is not needed, and is even wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For some cases I'd prefer slightly another, generic variant, assuming that, as a rule, default collection constructors return empty instances.

It would be better to name this method `NewIfDefault`. It can be useful not only for collections, so type constraint `IEnumerable<T>` is maybe redundant.

```
public static TCollection EmptyIfDefault<TCollection, T>(this TCollection collection)
        where TCollection: class, IEnumerable<T>, new()
    {
        return collection ?? new TCollection();
    }
```