# Check an object is not null before iterating over it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting an error `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` on the following:

```
 foreach (var pmt in payment.NewInvoiceViewModels
   .Where(x => x.PaymentReceived != 0) ?? 
    Enumerable.Empty<NewInvoiceViewModel>())
```

All I'm trying to do is check of payment.NewInvoiceViewModels is null before I iterate over it (if it is null, it causes an error).

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Your approach is correct. You can however write a generic extension method to improve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734380/check-for-null-in-foreach-loop

Comment: Hi Emrie - thanks - I thought it was correct, but if the object is empty, I get the Value cannot be null error - that's what I'm trying to get around.  The link to the other question, is what I'm doing (I believe).  Thanks, Mark

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi: No, the approach is most definitely *not* correct at the moment. Calling `Enumerable.Where(null, predicate)` will throw an exception - just as the OP is reporting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got the null-coalescing operator in the wrong place - currently you're calling `Where` on `payment.NewInvoiceModels` unconditionally and then checking whether the result will be null... it *never* will be (`Where` simply doesn't return null). You potentially want:

```
foreach (var pmt in (payment.NewInvoiceViewModels ?? 
                     Enumerable.Empty<NewInvoiceViewModel>())
                   .Where(x => x.PaymentReceived != 0))
```

Personally I'd extract this out though:

```
var allModels = payment.NewInvoiceViewModels ?? 
                     Enumerable.Empty<NewInvoiceViewModel>();

foreach (var pmt in allModels.Where(x => x.PaymentReceived != 0))
```

Or perhaps introduce an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> NullToEmpty(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Then:

```
foreach (var pmt in payment.NewInvoiceViewModels
                           .NullToEmpty()
                           .Where(x => x.PaymentReceived != 0))
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you - I'll mark as the answer as soon as SO allows (6 mins) - cheers, Mark

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this

```
if(payment.NewInvoiceViewModels!=null)
{
  foreach (var pmt in payment.NewInvoiceViewModels
   .Where(x => x.PaymentReceived != 0) ?? 
    Enumerable.Empty<NewInvoiceViewModel>())
}
```

Comment: he is allready dealing with problem by using Enumerable.Empty<NewInvoiceViewModel>(). Your answer is obviously worse.

Comment: Hi - thank you - so am I as well removing the: ?? 
    Enumerable.Empty<NewInvoiceViewModel>() - as I thought that is what that would do?  Thanks, Mark

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi: Not at all. If `payment.NewInvoiceViewModels` is null, then `Where` throws ArgumentNullException.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes my bad. I missed the .Where()