# c# Extension method Array.Empty .net 4.5

Tags: c#

I implemented `Array.Empty<T>` because want to use this code

```cs
foreach (Control c in controls.OrEmptyIfNull())
{
    this.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

[OrEmptyIfNull extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11734486/14102736)

but my program is using .NET version 4.5 and I don't want to change.

[Array.Emtpy](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/api/system.array.empty?view=netframework-4.6)

so coded below

```cs
public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static T[] Empty<T>(this Array array)
    {
        return EmptyArray<T>.Value;
    }

    public static IList<T> OrEmptyIfNull<T>(this IList<T> source)
    {
        return source ?? Array.Empty<T>();
    }

    internal static class EmptyArray<T>
    {
        public static readonly T[] Value = new T[0];
    }
}
```

but an error occurred this line `return source ?? Array.Empty<T>();`

> Error  CS0117  'Array' does not contain a definition for 'Empty'

how to use `Array.Empty()` or check before foreach List is null much prettier

Comment: Why not use standard LINQ? `public static IEnumerable<T> OrEmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Array.Empty<T>` is only available from *.Net 4.6* + you could easily just new up a `List<T>` or `new T[0];` both of which implement `IList<T>`

```
return source ?? new List<T>();

// or

return source ?? new T[0];
```

It's also worth a note, that the source code for `Array.Empty<T>` basically just references a static type for minimal allocations, so you could replicate this functionality fairly easily:

```
internal static class EmptyArray<T>
{
    public static readonly T[] Value = new T[0];
}

...

return source ?? EmptyArray<T>.Value;
```

<sub>***Note** : I would be skeptical about any of these extension methods considering the move to nullable types. However, since you are stuck in the 2012's there is probably little harm :)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You already have `EmptyArray<T>` defined, why not just use it?

```
return source ?? EmptyArray<T>.Value;
```