# Null check in foreach loop of JArray.Children()

Tags: c#, foreach, null

I want to check if JArray.Children() is null in the foreach loop.
I can do:

```
        if (jArrayJson == null)
        {
            return;
        }
```

but I want to do it in the foreach.
This is the different things I have tried:

```
    JArray jArrayJson = (JArray)token.SelectToken("text");
    foreach (JToken item in jArrayJson?.Children() ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()) // Wouldn't compile
    foreach (JToken item in jArrayJson?.Children()) // This will fail and not stop a null value
```

I saw this post about exention method, but I could not integrate the metod:
[Check for null in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734380/check-for-null-in-foreach-loop)

```
    public static IList<T> OrEmptyIfNull<T>(this IList<T> source)
    {
        return source ?? Array.Empty<T>();
    }



foreach (JToken item in jArrayJson?.Children().OrEmptyIfNull()) // Wouldn't compile
```

Comment: `?? Enumerable.Empty<JToken>()`, but doing the null check separately is probably clearer.

Comment: Thank you, I will use that check in the foreach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `Children()` returns a custom `JEnumerable` type that is actually a struct, so cannot be null, which makes the null propagation awkward.  So you could make this work using your first attempt, with a `JToken` in the type parameter (like Johnathan Barclay already suggested):

```
foreach (JToken item in jArrayJson?.Children() ?? Enumerable.Empty<JToken>())
{

}
```

Or I tweaked your extension method to work off a `JToken` itself:

```
public static JEnumerable<JToken> ChildrenOrEmptyIfNull(this JToken token)
{
    if(token == null)
    {
        return new JEnumerable<JToken>();
    }

    return token.Children();
}
```

which you could use like:

```
 foreach (JToken item in jArrayJson?.ChildrenOrEmptyIfNull())
 {

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the extension method as well, then I understand more about how to write these in the future.